# Using python sh module with git

Tags: python, git

I have the following code

```
import urllib2
import unicodedata
from sh import git

repo_name = "bitbucket.org/foo/foo.git"
repo_dir = "/home/foo/code"
user = "foo"
pwd = "foo"

git = git.bake(_tty_out=False, _cwd=repo_dir)
for file_name in git.diff('--name-only'):
    file_name_str=file_name.encode('ascii','ignore')
    file_name_str=file_name_str.strip()
    git("-c user.name=foo -c user.email='foo@bitbacket.org' commit -m 'no comments' group_vars/git_vars.yml")
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
sh.ErrorReturnCode_129:

  RAN: /usr/bin/git -c user.name=awsAnsibleViju -c user.email='awsAnsibleViju@bitbacket.org' commit -m 'no comments' /home/r_ansible/playbooks/group_vars/git_vars.yml

  STDOUT:

  STDERR:
Unknown option: -c user.name=awsAnsibleViju -c user.email='awsAnsibleViju@bitbacket.org' commit -m 'no comments' /home/r_ansible/playbooks/group_vars/git_vars.yml
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]
```

The main reason I am finding this difficult to troubleshoot is if I copy the output command  `-c user.name=foo -c user.email='foo@bitbacket.org' commit -m 'no comments' group_vars/git_vars.yml` to the terminal and add `$git` at the front of it file `group_vars/git_vars.yml` gets committed to the local repo fine

Comment: Maybe you're using some other version in the terminal than in your script?

Comment: apologies my original for was not 100% accurate. I should have stated that i use the exact same command as the sh module and I do not add just add git. So the command in the terminal I use `/usr/bin/git -c user.name=foo -c user.email='foo@bitbacket.org' commit -m 'no comments' group_vars/git_vars.yml` so should be the same git `/usr/bin/git/`

Comment: have you tried this http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html

Comment: I tried but I couldn't get my head around its API or the doc it provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to split your arguments.

your error message would read (added quotes and newlines):

```
RAN: /usr/bin/git "-c user.name=awsAnsibleViju -c 
                   user.email='awsAnsibleViju@bitbacket.org' commit -m 
                   'no comments' 
                   /home/r_ansible/playbooks/group_vars/git_vars.yml"
```

and `git` does not understand that (it takes the whole string as the first argument).

you can use [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) to split your arguments:

```
import shlex

args = shlex.split(("-c user.name=foo -c user.email='foo@bitbacket.org'"
                    " commit -m 'no comments' group_vars/git_vars.yml"))
# ['-c', 'user.name=foo', '-c', 'user.email=foo@bitbacket.org', 'commit',
#  '-m', 'no comments', 'group_vars/git_vars.yml']
```

and use that as

```
git(args)  # or: git(*args)
```

that is also what [the documentation](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/passing_arguments.html) says:

> When passing multiple arguments to a command, each argument must be a separate string:
>
> `tar("cvf", "/tmp/test.tar", "/my/home/directory/")`
>
> This *will not work*:
>
> `tar("cvf /tmp/test.tar /my/home/directory")`

note: when working with `git` i prefer [`gitpython`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/) over `sh`.

Comment: thanks for the resolution provided and equally important the clear explanation and links to the relevant doc's. I have tried to used `gitpython` but i found it's API and its doc incomprehensible (which I am sure is down to me)

Comment: @alexis i had a hard time starting with `gitpython` myself, i have to admit!